# Animated.Value does not exist in react-native-reanimated

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, react-native-reanimated

After updating expo SDK version, which forced me to update another packages accordingly. I started facing the following issue with `Animated.Value`, VSCode says that, property `Value` does not exist on type `Animated`.

importing as:

`import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';`

`react-native-reanimated` version is `3.6.2`.

[image]

But, when I run the app and go to the screen, it throws the following error:

```
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

This error is located at:
in StocksScreen (at SceneView.tsx:132)
in StaticContainer
in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:124)
in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:218)
in RCTView (at View.js:116)
in View (at Screen.tsx:63)
in RCTView (at View.js:116)
in View (at Background.tsx:13)
in Background (at Screen.tsx:58)
in Screen (at BottomTabView.tsx:135)
in RNSScreen (at createAnimatedComponent.js:54)
in Unknown (at src/index.native.tsx:314)
in Suspender (at src/index.tsx:40)
in Suspense (at src/index.tsx:39)
in Freeze (at src/index.native.tsx:206)
in DelayedFreeze (at src/index.native.tsx:313)
in InnerScreen (at src/index.native.tsx:566)
in Screen (at ScreenFallback.tsx:39)
in MaybeScreen (at BottomTabView.tsx:127)
in RNSScreenNavigationContainer (at src/index.native.tsx:398)
in ScreenContainer (at ScreenFallback.tsx:30)
in MaybeScreenContainer (at BottomTabView.tsx:93)
in RCTView (at View.js:116)
in View (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:42)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at BottomTabView.tsx:92)
in BottomTabView (at createBottomTabNavigator.tsx:118)
in PreventRemoveProvider (at useNavigationBuilder.tsx:718)
in NavigationContent (at useComponent.tsx:35)
in Unknown (at createBottomTabNavigator.tsx:117)
in BottomTabNavigator (at BottomTabNavigator.tsx:32)
in Suspense (at BottomTabNavigator.tsx:25)
in BottomTabNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:132)
in StaticContainer
in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:124)
in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:218)
in RCTView (at View.js:116)
in View (at DebugContainer.native.tsx:34)
in DebugContainer (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:82)
in MaybeNestedStack (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:325)
in RCTView (at View.js:116)
in View (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:318)
in RNSScreen (at createAnimatedComponent.js:54)
in Unknown (at src/index.native.tsx:314)
in Suspender (at src/index.tsx:40)
in Suspense (at src/index.tsx:39)
in Freeze (at src/index.native.tsx:206)
in DelayedFreeze (at src/index.native.tsx:313)
in InnerScreen (at src/index.native.tsx:566)
in Screen (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:253)
in SceneView (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:413)
in Suspender (at src/index.tsx:40)
in Suspense (at src/index.tsx:39)
in Freeze (at src/index.native.tsx:206)
in DelayedFreeze (at src/index.native.tsx:220)
in RNSScreenStack (at src/index.native.tsx:227)
in ScreenStack (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:401)
in NativeStackViewInner (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:474)
in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:92)
in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:46)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:473)
in NativeStackView (at createNativeStackNavigator.tsx:72)
in PreventRemoveProvider (at useNavigationBuilder.tsx:718)
in NavigationContent (at useComponent.tsx:35)
in Unknown (at createNativeStackNavigator.tsx:71)
in NativeStackNavigator (at StackNavigator.tsx:16)
in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:430)
in BaseNavigationContainer (at NavigationContainer.tsx:132)
in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:131)
in NavigationContainerInner (at StackNavigator.tsx:15)
in StackNavigator (at App.tsx:15)
in CurrencyContextProvider (at App.tsx:14)
in NewsContextProvider (at App.tsx:13)
in CategoryContextProvider (at App.tsx:12)
in App (at withDevTools.ios.js:25)
in withDevTools(App) (at renderApplication.js:57)
in RCTView (at View.js:116)
in View (at AppContainer.js:127)
in RCTView (at View.js:116)
in View (at AppContainer.js:155)
in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:50)
in main(RootComponent) (at renderApplication.js:67), js engine: hermes
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

This error is located at:
in StocksScreen (at SceneView.tsx:132)
in StaticContainer
in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:124)
in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:218)
in RCTView (at View.js:116)
in View (at Screen.tsx:63)
in RCTView (at View.js:116)
in View (at Background.tsx:13)
in Background (at Screen.tsx:58)
in Screen (at BottomTabView.tsx:135)
in RNSScreen (at createAnimatedComponent.js:54)
in Unknown (at src/index.native.tsx:314)
in Suspender (at src/index.tsx:40)
in Suspense (at src/index.tsx:39)
in Freeze (at src/index.native.tsx:206)
in DelayedFreeze (at src/index.native.tsx:313)
in InnerScreen (at src/index.native.tsx:566)
in Screen (at ScreenFallback.tsx:39)
in MaybeScreen (at BottomTabView.tsx:127)
in RNSScreenNavigationContainer (at src/index.native.tsx:398)
in ScreenContainer (at ScreenFallback.tsx:30)
in MaybeScreenContainer (at BottomTabView.tsx:93)
in RCTView (at View.js:116)
in View (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:42)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at BottomTabView.tsx:92)
in BottomTabView (at createBottomTabNavigator.tsx:118)
in PreventRemoveProvider (at useNavigationBuilder.tsx:718)
in NavigationContent (at useComponent.tsx:35)
in Unknown (at createBottomTabNavigator.tsx:117)
in BottomTabNavigator (at BottomTabNavigator.tsx:32)
in Suspense (at BottomTabNavigator.tsx:25)
in BottomTabNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:132)
in StaticContainer
in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:124)
in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:218)
in RCTView (at View.js:116)
in View (at DebugContainer.native.tsx:34)
in DebugContainer (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:82)
in MaybeNestedStack (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:325)
in RCTView (at View.js:116)
in View (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:318)
in RNSScreen (at createAnimatedComponent.js:54)
in Unknown (at src/index.native.tsx:314)
in Suspender (at src/index.tsx:40)
in Suspense (at src/index.tsx:39)
in Freeze (at src/index.native.tsx:206)
in DelayedFreeze (at src/index.native.tsx:313)
in InnerScreen (at src/index.native.tsx:566)
in Screen (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:253)
in SceneView (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:413)
in Suspender (at src/index.tsx:40)
in Suspense (at src/index.tsx:39)
in Freeze (at src/index.native.tsx:206)
in DelayedFreeze (at src/index.native.tsx:220)
in RNSScreenStack (at src/index.native.tsx:227)
in ScreenStack (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:401)
in NativeStackViewInner (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:474)
in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:92)
in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:46)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:473)
in NativeStackView (at createNativeStackNavigator.tsx:72)
in PreventRemoveProvider (at useNavigationBuilder.tsx:718)
in NavigationContent (at useComponent.tsx:35)
in Unknown (at createNativeStackNavigator.tsx:71)
in NativeStackNavigator (at StackNavigator.tsx:16)
in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:430)
in BaseNavigationContainer (at NavigationContainer.tsx:132)
in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:131)
in NavigationContainerInner (at StackNavigator.tsx:15)
in StackNavigator (at App.tsx:15)
in CurrencyContextProvider (at App.tsx:14)
in NewsContextProvider (at App.tsx:13)
in CategoryContextProvider (at App.tsx:12)
in App (at withDevTools.ios.js:25)
in withDevTools(App) (at renderApplication.js:57)
in RCTView (at View.js:116)
in View (at AppContainer.js:127)
in RCTView (at View.js:116)
in View (at AppContainer.js:155)
in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:50)
in main(RootComponent) (at renderApplication.js:67), js engine: hermes
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your import of ```Animated```?

Comment: import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';

Comment: Try ```import { Animated } from 'react-native';```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the right syntax, Animated module from 'react-native-reanimated' differs from the one in 'react-native'.

### [Using a shared value](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/your-first-animation#using-a-shared-value)

```
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import Animated, { useSharedValue } from 'react-native-reanimated';

export default function App() {
  const width = useSharedValue(100);

  const handlePress = () => {
    width.value = width.value + 50;
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          width,
          height: 100,
          backgroundColor: 'violet',
        }}
      />
      <Button onPress={handlePress} title="Click me" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

### [Using an animation function:](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/your-first-animation#using-an-animation-function)

```
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import Animated, { useSharedValue, withSpring } from 'react-native-reanimated';

export default function App() {
  const width = useSharedValue(100);

  const handlePress = () => {
    width.value = withSpring(width.value + 50);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          width,
          height: 100,
          backgroundColor: 'violet',
        }}
      />
      <Button onPress={handlePress} title="Click me" />
    </View>
  );
}
```